# How to append a dictionary to key in another dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop

So I want my end output to look like this:

```
answer = {'A':{1,2,3,4},'B':{1,2,3,4}}
```

How can I do this? I have a few questions though.

1. How do I make a dictionary without a key pair value. Like `{1,2,3,4}`
2. How do I append the `{1,2,3,4}` to a key (`'A'`).
3. How do I append the `A` into the main dictionary(`answer`)

Essentially I am trying to make this bit in a loop `'A':{1,2,3,4}`. Then outside the loop append it to `answer`.

Comment: Please ask only one question at once. Also if you're asking about *output*, make sure to include *input*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{1,2,3,4}` is a [`set`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp), not a `dict`.

You can add the `A` key and its value (the `set`) like so:

```
answer = {}
answer["A"] = {1,2,3,4}
```

If you have a `set`, you can `add`:

```
>>> s = {1,2}
>>> s
{1, 2}
>>> s.add(3)
>>> s
{1, 2, 3}
>>> s.add(4)
>>> s
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

To iterate:

```
>>> for item in answer['A']:
...   print(item)
...
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Ohh... its a set... That makes so much sense. How do I append to a set?

Comment: So to define an empty set is it `s = {}`? Then how do you define an empty dictionary?

Comment: that's an empty dictionary. you have to do `set()` to define an empty set

Comment: `s = set()`. For `dict` : `d = {}` is the same as `d = dict()`

Comment: @JacobIRR last question before I accept the answer. when `answer = {'A': {1, 2, 3, 4}}`. How do I iterate over `A`'s set?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a dictionary like that given a list of keys and a set you can do:

```
list_of_keys = ["A", "B", "C"]
some_set = {1,2,3,4}
my_dict = {key: some_set for key in list_of_keys}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why you want to use dictionary and append values into it?

You can use a dictionaries of list:

```
# Outer Loop
  try: answer[i] # i = 'A', 'B'
  except KeyError: answer[i] = []

  # Inner Loop
    answer[i].append(j) # j = 1, 2, 3, 4

print(answer) # {'A':[1,2,2,3,4],'B':[1,1,2,3,4]}
```

If you do not want duplicates then you can use a set instead of a list.

```
# Outer Loop
  try: answer[i] # i = 'A', 'B'
  except KeyError: answer[i] = set()

  # Inner Loop
    answer[i].add(j) # j = 1, 2, 3, 4

print(answer) # {'A':(1,2,3,4),'B':(1,2,3,4)}
```

Hope this helps, Cheers!